# Excel Formula - excact match for warpped numbers

Tags: excel-formula

Need assistance with below formula to find exact match in wrapped text and if not matched,cell to be empty.

```
=IF(ISNONTEXT(FIND($K2,MasterList!$A$2:$A$10000)),INDEX(MasterList!B$2:B$10000,MATCH("*"&$K2&"*",MasterList!$A$2:$A$10000,0)),"")
```

Have numbers as below is single cell

```
"10.246.164.62
10.247.176.30
10.247.176.32
10.247.176.33
192.168.7.10"

"10.246.164.6
10.247.176.3
10.247.176.32
10.247.176.33
192.168.7.10"
```

Thank You

Comment: I may be missing something - can't you just `IFERROR` a non-range `VLOOKUP` without the wildcards (`"*"`) added to the text?

Comment: can you please provide complete formula to test. Not familiar with excel formulas.

Comment: You can use the "Function Builder" in Excel to explain the functions,  but it's written pretty much as it reads: `=`[`IFERROR`](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/iferror-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611)`(`[`VLOOKUP`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)`($K2, MasterList!$A:$B, 2, FALSE), "")`

Comment: Doesn't work if wrapped text . searching for 10.247.176.30 ..can't find with above formula. Have below in single cell.     "10.246.164.62
10.247.176.30
10.247.176.32
10.247.176.33
192.168.7.10"